# How to conditionally display possible answers to multiselect (checkbox) questions based on previously entered information in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I would like to have the end user answer a checkbox question and then have subsequent checkbox questions display possible answers based on that previously answered question. For instance if the first question is "select which days of the week you ate ice cream" I would like the subsequent questions to be able to prompt the user with possible answers from that first question (e.g. "Of those days you ate ice cream, on which days did you eat strawberry ice cream") etc.

Is it possible to conditionally filter possible answers to checkbox questions in CommCare? And if so how should I go about configuring my form to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible using Lookup Tables, which allow filtering items with an xpath expression.